# Why Mathematica is not assuming real variable as real?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am dealing with the situation where despite of specifying my variables `b1` and `c` to be greater than zero, Mathematica still returns the output with `Re[b1+c]`

```
x = a - (b1 + c)/2 I

FullSimplify[
 Im[x],
 {a >= 0, b1 >= 0, c >= 0}
 ]
(* -(1/2) Re[b1 + c] *)
```

Comment: Next time please take the time to contsruct a minimal example and use readable formatting in your post. See my edit for reference.

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

mat1 = Simplify[({{a - (b1 + c)/2 I, d}, {d, a - (b2 - c)/2 I}})];

mat2 = ({{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}});
```

The primary tool for simplifying complex expressions is [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html)

```
MatrixForm[
 Simplify@
  ComplexExpand[({{Re[mat1[[1]][[1]]], 
      Re[mat1[[1]][[2]]], -Im[mat1[[1]][[1]]], -Im[mat1[[1]][[2]]]}, {Re[
       mat1[[2]][[1]]], 
      Re[mat1[[2]][[2]]], -Im[mat1[[2]][[1]]], -Im[mat1[[2]][[2]]]}, {Im[
       mat1[[1]][[1]]], Im[mat1[[1]][[2]]], Re[mat1[[1]][[1]]], 
      Re[mat1[[1]][[2]]]}, {Im[mat1[[2]][[1]]], Im[mat1[[2]][[2]]], 
      Re[mat1[[2]][[1]]], Re[mat1[[2]][[2]]]}})]]
```

[image]

This result shows that you need only require that the variables are real rather than the more restrictive nonnegative.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that while `Simplify` and `Refine` are "safe", in that they shouldn't make invalid assumptions, `ComplexExpand` assumes that variables are real, unless told otherwise.  I treat `ComplexExpand` (and `PowerExpand`) as unsafe, that is every use needs careful examination to ensure that their assumptions are met.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know really know why `FullSimplify` doesn't work, but `Refine` does

```
Assuming[{a >= 0, d >= 0, b1 >= 0, b2 >= 0, c >= 0}, 
 Refine[({{Re[mat1[[1]][[1]]], 
     Re[mat1[[1]][[2]]], -Im[mat1[[1]][[1]]], -Im[
       mat1[[1]][[2]]]}, {Re[mat1[[2]][[1]]], 
     Re[mat1[[2]][[2]]], -Im[mat1[[2]][[1]]], -Im[
       mat1[[2]][[2]]]}, {Im[mat1[[1]][[1]]], Im[mat1[[1]][[2]]], 
     Re[mat1[[1]][[1]]], Re[mat1[[1]][[2]]]}, {Im[mat1[[2]][[1]]], 
     Im[mat1[[2]][[2]]], Re[mat1[[2]][[1]]], Re[mat1[[2]][[2]]]}})]]
(* {{a, d, (b1 + c)/2, 0}, {d, a, 0, (b2 - c)/2}, {1/2 (-b1 - c),
   0, a, d}, {0, 1/2 (-b2 + c), d, a}} *)
```

Occasionally, a more specific simplification, such as `Refine` finds what you want when the more general one, `FullSimplify`, does not.  Presumably `FullSimplify` tries a lot of other things before it gives up.